# Inno Setup: TFolderTreeView root

Tags: inno-setup

Is it possible to specify the 'Thic PC' as root for TFolderTreeView control?
At the moment TFolderTreeView displays to me only C and D drives.

[image]

Here is a part of my code:

```
var
  FolderTreeView: TFolderTreeView;
  Form: TSetupForm;
begin
    Form := CreateCustomForm();
    FolderTreeView := TFolderTreeView.Create(Form);
    with FolderTreeView do
    begin
        Parent := Form;  
    end;   
   Form.ShowModal();
end;
```

Comment: I do not think this is possible. But anyway, what do you want to show there?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl just an ordinary [browse tree](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/BrowseForFolder.png)

Comment: Neither the "Browse for folder" dialog of Inno Setup shows the "virtual" folders.

Comment: Write a plug-in with custom TreeView compoenent to show such items.